# seasonal_periods has not been provided and index does not have a known freq. You must provide seasonal_periods

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

When trying to train a model with Darts I get these ValueErrors: "ValueError: seasonal_periods has not been provided and index does not have a known freq. You must provide seasonal_periods" and "ValueError: freq T not understood. Please report if you think this is in error."
Here is my Code:

```
series = pd.read_csv('Saeule2processed.csv', header=0,delimiter=";", squeeze=True, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing
train, val = series.split_before(0.8)
model = ExponentialSmoothing()
model.fit(train)
prediction = model.predict(len(val))
```

Does anybody have a solution or got this same Error?

My Data looks like this:

```
TimeNum
2021-11-02 14:28:00    2380.000000
2021-11-02 14:29:00    2393.555556
2021-11-02 14:30:00    2388.444444
2021-11-02 14:31:00    2388.000000
2021-11-02 14:32:00    2387.826087
2021-11-02 14:33:00    2390.888889
2021-11-02 14:34:00    2386.086957
2021-11-02 14:35:00    2377.777778
2021-11-02 14:36:00    2374.888889
2021-11-02 14:37:00    2385.000000
2021-11-02 14:38:00    2381.111111
2021-11-02 14:39:00    2377.173913
2021-11-02 14:40:00    2384.000000
2021-11-02 14:41:00    2371.282051
2021-11-02 14:42:00    2387.555556
Name: EV2.P123, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/552

```
from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing
from darts.utils.utils import SeasonalityMode
model = ExponentialSmoothing(seasonal=SeasonalityMode.NONE)
model.fit(train)
prediction = model.predict(len(val), num_samples=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you didn't specify the time index of your time series. you can modify your code as follows:

```
from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing
from darts import TimeSeries
df = pd.read_csv('Saeule2processed.csv', header=0, delimiter=";", squeeze=True, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
df.columns = ['time', 'value']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], infer_datetime_format=True)    
series = TimeSeries.from_series(df['value'])   

train, val = series.split_before(0.8)
model = ExponentialSmoothing()
model.fit(train)
prediction = model.predict(len(val))
```

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?